# Show how to find the cubic root

Tags: radicals, cubics

Show how to find the cubic root of surds of the form $A+\sqrt[3]{B}$, and deduce that

$$\sqrt[3]{{\sqrt[3]{2} - 1}}= \sqrt[3]{1 \over 9}-\sqrt[3]{2 \over 9}+\sqrt[3]{4 \over 9}$$

Comment: What is the point of your question?

Comment: The point is that I am not going to do your homework for you, if you haven't even tried doing it. Others might feel differently.

Comment: First of all that's not my homework

Comment: OK, why not explain where the question comes from, then? As you are well aware, there is a lot of homework questions being asked here, and the form of your question suggests homework.

Comment: Ok. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.9228&rep=rep1&type=pdf Any idea ?

Comment: @Ewin, it is very common, and in my opinion needed, for people to ask you what you have tried and where you got stuck in the problem. If it is not homework, explain so. A lot of people, including myself, do not want this website to turn into Chegg. Also, the question that Igor asked you is for your own benefit. That way people can see where you are stuck and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is must be useful to think in something.

${\sqrt[3]{{\sqrt[3]{2} - 1}}}.\frac{\sqrt[3]{{(\sqrt[3]{2})^2+\sqrt[3]{2}+1}}}{\sqrt[3]{{(\sqrt[3]{2})^2+\sqrt[3]{2}+1}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{{(\sqrt[3]{2})^2+\sqrt[3]{2}+1}}}$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{{(\sqrt[3]{2})^2+\sqrt[3]{2}+1}}}.\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{3}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{{3.(\sqrt[3]{2^2})+3.(\sqrt[3]{2})+3}}}$

$\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{{(\sqrt[3]{2}+1)^3}}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{(\sqrt[3]{2}+1)}.\frac{{{{(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{2}+1)}}}}{{{{(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{2}+1)}}}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}.(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{2}+1)}{2+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{9}}$

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Ramanujan's radicals, that's a different story, and one that has been [very nicely addressed.](http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/uploads/tx_sibibtex/DenestRamanujansNestedRadicals.pdf) By Johannes Blomer.